# application using graphics, only displays red X's over main window and control

Tags: vb.net, graphics

the code i have that interacts with e.graphics is

```
'clear area
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, 600, 800)
'draw sand
For Each i In world
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(i.getcolor, i.getx, i.gety, 1, 1)
Next
```

here are the variable areas of my two classes, along with their new functions; assume that the get lines do what you think they do.

```
Public Class Sand
    Private x As Integer
    Private y As Integer
    Private type As element
Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal type As element)
    Me.x = x
    Me.y = y
    Me.type = type
End Sub

Public Class element
    Public color As Color
    Public weight As Integer = 1
    Public spread As Double = 0.5
    Public text As String = "null"
    Public Sub New(ByVal c As Color, ByVal w As Integer, ByVal s As Double, ByVal t As String)
        color = c
        weight = w
        spread = s
        text = t
    End Sub
```

here is the spot in my program that dimensions the world variable and such.

```
Private world As List(Of Sand)
Private paused As Boolean = False
Private openbottom As Boolean = False
Private selected As Integer = 0
Private elements As List(Of element)
'DEBUG VARIABLES
Private debugmode As Boolean = True
Private framenum As Integer = 0
```

and here is the area in my debug portion that makes a 4 grains of sand in 2 different elements.

```
elements.Add(New element(Color.Azure, 1, 1, "Test El 1"))
elements.Add(New element(Color.Aqua, 1, 1, "Test El 2"))
world.Add(New Sand(240, 400, elements(1)))
world.Add(New Sand(440, 200, elements(1)))
world.Add(New Sand(340, 100, elements(2)))
world.Add(New Sand(540, 400, elements(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

A red x's over the main window means that your custom drawing code launches an exception. Is *world* null? Is some *i* null?

Comment: I will check to see if something might be.

Comment: i have posted some more of the code, i think the problem might be in the way i am using the lists.

Comment: i have added a part to make it start without running the timer, and to not complete the pain function without the user telling it to start. and the red X does not appear until the pain command is called. although when trying to debug, i put these two lines at the end of the loadup debug and they do nothing.         MessageBox.Show(world(1).getx.ToString)
MessageBox.Show(world(2).getelement())
no messagebox ever shows up.